# How to solve $y^2+x^2y'=xyy'$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have:

$$y^2+x^2y'=xyy'$$
with substitution $y = tx$

I got:

$$t^2x^2+x^2(xt'+t) = tx^2(xt'+t)$$
$$t^2x^2+x^3t'+x^2t = t'tx^3+t^2x^2$$
$$x^3t'+x^2t = t'tx^3$$
$$x^2(xt'+t) = t'tx^3$$
$$xt'+t=t'tx$$

what am I supossed to do next? (if I am right, of course)

Comment: You need to have "$=$" in a equation.

Comment: Assuming you did everything correct, $t' x(1 - t) = -t$, which is a seperable DE.

Comment: As aid by @ A---B, $y^2+x^2y'+xyy'$ isn't a differential equation,  $y^2+x^2y'+xyy'=0$ is one. Please correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$xt'+t=t'tx\\\implies xt'-xtt'=-t\\\implies xt'(1-t)=-t\\\implies xt'=-\frac{t}{1-t}\\x\dfrac{dt}{dx}=-\frac{t}{1-t}\\\implies x \dfrac{1}{dx}=-\frac{t}{1-t}\dfrac{1}{dt}\\\implies \frac{1}{x}dx=-\frac{1-t}{t} dt\\\implies \frac{1}{x}dx=\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)dt\\\implies \int\frac{1}{x}dx=\int\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)dt$$

Answer (score 0):

$$t'x(1-t) + t = 0 $$

$$ t' = \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{t}{(t-1)x}$$

Apply separation of variables to get

$$ \left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)dt = \frac{dx}{x} $$

You can take it from here.